# angular 4 recaptcha not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in angular 4. I am trying to add recaptcha on my page without using other node_modules.

HTML

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="onCaptchaComplete" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

TS

```
  private onCaptchaComplete(response: any) {
    console.log('reCAPTCHA response recieved:');
    console.log(response.success);
    console.log(response.token);
   }
```

But i am getting `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onCaptchaComplete` Please help me where is my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with recaptcha itself, it just cant find your onCaptchaComplete function. This can have many reasons, eventually its simply because you set it private and its not in the scope. There is also an official open bug for it on the github page https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/issues/175 try asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is inside a class, which means that's it not a global function (`window.onCaptchaComplete`) as you've stated in `data-callback`.

You'll need to have it globally declared for your current approach to work. You could do this in `main.ts`, for example. Beware of the optimizers though which might minimize function names: configure them correctly for this function is you're using such a tool.

In general, it's not a good approach to use a module which relies on global functions when you're using Angular -- you kinda lose the whole point of Angular. I suggest you try finding a different module, maybe even some already prepared for Angular.